# JavaScript: Image height based on window height

Tags: javascript

In the code below I would like to only include `height="246" width="188` of the image if the `var h` in the JavaScript is `< 600`.

```
<script>
  var h = window.innerHeight
  || document.documentElement.clientHeight
  || document.body.clientHeight;
</script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <center><img class="visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" src="{% static 'intro_small.png' %}" alt="str8RED" height="246" width="188"/></center>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-info btn-block .btn-lg" style="font-size: 20px">WHAT IS str8RED?</a><a href="https://str8red.com/selectteams/0/0/" style="font-size: 20px" class="btn btn-success btn-block .btn-lg">PLAY str8RED <span style="font-size: 20px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to give the the image an `id` and use that along with `.innerHTML`, but had no joy.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: There's not much of a question here, just a statement of what you'd like. It sounds like you're expecting the volunteers of Stack Overflow to write your code for you. It would be better if you followed [ask] and included what you've tried, what research you've done to find an answer, etc.

Comment: You could do that with a CSS `@media` query.

Comment: Mike, great point.  My fault for putting it up before bed.  My apologies.  Added a bit more but should rewrite tomorrow perhaps.

yuriy, if you could elaborate that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new class to the image and use that class for adding css or like @yuriy636 said you can also use CSS `@media`

```
    <script>
      var h = window.innerHeight
      || document.documentElement.clientHeight
      || document.body.clientHeight;
if(h < 600){
$('.test').css('height','246');
$('.test').css('width','188');
}
    </script>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <center><img class=" test visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" src="{% static 'intro_small.png' %}" alt="str8RED" height="246" width="188"/></center>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-info btn-block .btn-lg" style="font-size: 20px">WHAT IS str8RED?</a><a href="https://str8red.com/selectteams/0/0/" style="font-size: 20px" class="btn btn-success btn-block .btn-lg">PLAY str8RED <span style="font-size: 20px" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Copied code in and no joy, appreciate your swift reply.  Get the feeling it's me.  Will sleep on it.